# D2FS within workflow method

Tags: jboss, documentum, emc

I´m trying to use D2FS services within a workflow method, but im getting the following error:

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
    Two classes have the same XML type name "address". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
        this problem is related to the following location:
            at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference$Address
            at public com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference$Address com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference.addr
            at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference
        this problem is related to the following location:
            at javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference$Address
            at private javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference$Address javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference.address
            at javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference
    Two classes have the same XML type name "elements". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
        this problem is related to the following location:
            at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference$Elements
            at public com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference$Elements com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference.referenceProperties
            at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.MemberSubmissionEndpointReference
        this problem is related to the following location:
            at javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference$Elements
            at private javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference$Elements javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference.referenceParameters
            at javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing.W3CEndpointReference
```

I tried to update the jaxws-rt libraries and started getting the new error:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: ClassException: attempting to castjar:file:/C:/Documentum/jboss4.3.0/server/DctmServer_MethodServer/deploy/bpm.ear/APP-INF/lib/jaxws-api.jar!/javax/xml/ws/spi/Provider.classtojar:file:/C:/Documentum/jboss4.3.0/jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar!/javax/xml/ws/spi/Provider.class
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:94)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
    at com.emc.d2fs.schemas.models.ModelPortService.<init>(ModelPortService.java:46)
    at com.emc.cgd.methodsWorkflow.DispatchExtStorageUpdateData.doTask(DispatchExtStorageUpdateData.java:45)
    at com.documentum.bpm.rtutil.WorkflowMethod.execute(WorkflowMethod.java:214)
    at com.documentum.bpm.rtutil.AbstractWorkflowMethod.executeMethod(AbstractWorkflowMethod.java:27)
    at com.documentum.bpm.rtutil.GenericWorkflowMethod.execute(GenericWorkflowMethod.java:124)
    at com.documentum.bpm.rtutil.GenericWorkflowMethod.execute(GenericWorkflowMethod.java:65)
    at com.documentum.mthdservlet.DfMethodRunner.runIt(Unknown Source)
    at com.documentum.mthdservlet.AMethodRunner.runAndReturnStatus(Unknown Source)
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Im using:

- JBoss 4.3
- JAX-WS Implementation 2.2

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On tomcat I had to add following jars to the tomcat lib:

- jaxws-api.jar
- jaxws-rt.jar
- stax-ex.jar
- streambuffer.jar

Perhaps this will resolver the problem on jBoss as well.